# Allow only 5 countries to access my page may lead to get lost or removed from search engines?

Tags: search, google, yahoo

Because my resource are limited, I need to cut off strangers (inc. USA) for visiting my page. People from the middle of Europe are allowed (Germany, France, Hungary, Poland etc) are allowed. If they are strangers, they will see only a message that they have been restricted for accessing the page. If I restrict them it may lead to get removed or *self-banned* from the search engines?

Thank you !

Comment: How to you handle European traffic that is routed via US?

Answer (score 1):

That depends from where the search engines actually crawl your site.

Google, for example, usually crawls from USA, so you would block it from indexing your actual site, if you deny USA IPs.

On the other hand, you can't allow only GoogleBot, because that is considered [Cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking), so you have to be very careful.

One solution would be to use a JavaScript file that blocks access to your site, this file has to be blocked using robots.txt, so Google isn't allowed to read it.

Have a look here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/thqhs2Mrmtw

And here's some general info about Cloaking: https://plus.google.com/u/0/109412257237874861202/posts/EbRoyMnqggQ